# Solr DataImportHandler RegexTranslator usage: skip field by pattern

Tags: sql, regex, solr, import

I am reading the value of **column_name** from **table_name** to field **fieldName** of my entity and I want to exclude a certain value **negatory**. I found that I can do this with a conditional expression in the SQL, e.g.:

```
select 
   CASE WHEN column_name = 'negatory' 
      THEN null 
      ELSE column_name 
   END AS fieldName 
from table_name
```

However, I was not able to get my original implementation using `RegexTransformer` to work (pseudo-code *data-config.xml*):

```
<entity query="select column_name from table_name">
    <field column="fieldName" sourceColName="column_name" regex="^(?!negatory)$" />
</entity>
```

I think the SQL solution is fine (probably better), but I am curious to understand how/whether it could be done via RegexTransformer.

## Update (incorporating stribizhev's suggestion)

The more I think about it, I'm not convinced a negative lookahead can do what I want. I ran a quick test:

```
    Pattern[] pp = new Pattern[] {
        Pattern.compile("^(?!negatory)$"), // original attempt, only matches empty string
        Pattern.compile("^((?!negatory).)*$"), // suggestion from stribizhev
        Pattern.compile("^(?!.*negatory).*$"), // suggestion from stribizhev
        Pattern.compile("^((?!negatory)|(.+(?=negatory)?.*)|(.*(?=negatory)?.+))$") // latest attempt
    };
    String[] ss = new String[] {
        "contains substring negatory but should match",
        "should match",
        "negatory start should match",
        "should match with trailing negatory",
        "negatory"
    };
    int pi = 0;
    for (Pattern p : pp) {
        ++pi;
        int si = 0;
        for (String s : ss) {
            ++si;
            Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
            if (m.find()) {
                int count = m.groupCount();
                System.out.println(String.format("%s groups for pattern/string: %s/%s", count, pi, si));
                for (int i = 0; i <= count; ++i) {
                    System.out.println(String.format("\tgroup %s: %s", i, m.group(i)));
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println(String.format("no match for pattern/string: %s/%s", pi, si));
            }
        }
    }
```

for the following results:

```
no match for pattern/string: 1/1
no match for pattern/string: 1/2
no match for pattern/string: 1/3
no match for pattern/string: 1/4
no match for pattern/string: 1/5
no match for pattern/string: 2/1
1 groups for pattern/string: 2/2
    group 0: should match
    group 1: h
no match for pattern/string: 2/3
no match for pattern/string: 2/4
no match for pattern/string: 2/5
no match for pattern/string: 3/1
0 groups for pattern/string: 3/2
    group 0: should match
no match for pattern/string: 3/3
no match for pattern/string: 3/4
no match for pattern/string: 3/5
3 groups for pattern/string: 4/1
    group 0: contains substring negatory but should match
    group 1: contains substring negatory but should match
    group 2: contains substring negatory but should match
    group 3: null
3 groups for pattern/string: 4/2
    group 0: should match
    group 1: should match
    group 2: should match
    group 3: null
3 groups for pattern/string: 4/3
    group 0: negatory start should match
    group 1: negatory start should match
    group 2: negatory start should match
    group 3: null
3 groups for pattern/string: 4/4
    group 0: should match with trailing negatory
    group 1: should match with trailing negatory
    group 2: should match with trailing negatory
    group 3: null
3 groups for pattern/string: 4/5
    group 0: negatory
    group 1: negatory
    group 2: negatory
    group 3: null
```

None of the patterns work as intended; the intention is that all but the last string satisfies the matcher (ignoring whatever the strings themselves say). It seems my intention just doesn't match the intended use of the negative lookahead.

## Solved (thanks to stribizhev)

Solution: `^(?!negatory$).*$`

The thing I was missing in all my attempts was the end-anchor `$` in the negative lookahead group.

Comment: Try `^((?!negatory).)*$` or `^(?!.*negatory).*$`, and if it does not work, it will not likely to work at all that way.

Comment: See question for update...

Comment: Your `^(?!negatory)$` regex matches empty string only. My both regexes match a string not containing `negatory`. `this should not match` does not contain that word, so it is matched.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that, there's nothing positive in my original pattern (only negative lookahead). Also, I apologize for the poor choice of strings. I'll update my test to try and clarify it.

Comment: Oh, looks like you just need [`^(?!negatory$).*$`](https://regex101.com/r/yT1cM0/1), right?

Comment: I think that's it! I have to think about it some more to make sense of it but that seems to work.

Comment: Posted, please feel free to drop any comment if there is anything unclear about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the following regex:

```
^(?!negatory$).*$
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/yT1cM0/1)

**REGEX EXPLANATION**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!negatory$)` - negative lookahead making sure that there is no `negatory` right at the beginning of the string and right at the end of the string
- `.*$` - match any 0 or more characters other than a newline up to the end of string.

Comment: That regex passes my tests. I'm still trying to get it to work in the DIH (still curious) but I'll probably did end up sticking with the SQL solution in the DIH. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I confirmed it works in the RegexTransformer during import.